# dimension of a single vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

what are the dimensions of a single vector such as
$
\begin{bmatrix}
10 \\
20 \\
30 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$?

I am understand when we have a matrix we can determine the rank by bringing the matrix into echelon form, but I'm confused about a single vector. My gut says 1. But would like to understand better.

thank you

Comment: What is the *meaning* of dimension of a vector?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos if we were to place this point in n-dimensional space, what would $n$ be? Sorry - I'm new to linear algebra...

Comment: Is that supposed to be an answer to my question?

Comment: yes (and sorry for not being clear with how I'm explaining this) - I'm asking what dimensional space would be required to place this point in a graph?

Comment: If you are working over a field $F$, then that vector is an element of $F^3$.

Comment: There are 3 1-dimensional, 3 2-dimensional, 1 3-dimensional spaces I can think of right away in which you can place that vector. With only giving one vector, you are leaving that question up to interpretation and one can answer it however they like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by dimension, you mean the rank of the vector viewed as a $3\times 1$ matrix, then you can easily bring that into row echelon Form as well. What would come out then?

However, vectors do not have dimensions in Linear Algebra, but vector spaces do. So, your question as stated doesn't make sense, but I think you meant the thing above, right?

Comment: Thanks @Manatee Pink! Sorry for the confusion. I'm quite new to linear algebra. I consider two questions then: 1) So if we think of the rank of this vector, I'm assuming it would be 1,  since we could build the rest of the vector using row operations?  2) Then how about dimensional space? ie. if i was to plot this somewhere in a graph, would I need a 3 dimensional graph? So would it be 3-dimensional space?

Comment: 1) The rank of the vector viewed as a matrix is 1,yes. Notice how I write "viewed as a matrix" since the rank is only defined for matrices and a vector is usually not a matrix. So you cannot say the rank of the vector actually. \\ 2) Since you are only talking about a single vector, you cannot talk about dimension and space. Those only make sense for a whole set of vectors which are closed under linear combinations, which is called a vector space. Only for the whole picture it makes sense to talk about dimensions and space.

Comment: OK -- thanks so much -- that makes more sense